# Nginx and Centos Optimizations

Tags: linux, nginx, centos6

I have installed and optimized nginx on two different machines.
Machine1 : With 2 CPU's and considerable lower system resources.
Machine2: With 4 CPU's and higher system resources.

But they still fail at about the same number of requests. Maybe there is something else that is limiting the server maybe soem OS settings and not necessarily nginx settings.

I have nginx set up with php-fpm on CentOS -6.3. I have increased the ulimit -n values in both systems.

This is my nginx.conf

```
user          nginx;
worker_processes  2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 16384;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
   worker_connections  5000;
# essential for linux, optmized to serve many clients with each thread
   use epoll;
   multi_accept on;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    access_log off;
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!EDH:!AESGCM;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    keepalive_requests 100000;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your PHP FPM pool settings `pm.*` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

> pm.max_children int
>
> The number of child processes to be created when pm is set to static and the maximum number of child processes to be created when pm is set to dynamic. This option is mandatory.
>
> This option sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be served. Equivalent to the ApacheMaxClients directive with mpm_prefork and to the PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN environment variable in the original PHP FastCGI.
>
> pm.start_servers int
>
> The number of child processes created on startup. Used only when pm is set to dynamic. Default Value: min_spare_servers + (max_spare_servers - min_spare_servers) / 2.
> pm.min_spare_servers int
>
> The desired minimum number of idle server processes. Used only when pm is set to dynamic. Also mandatory in this case.
>
> pm.max_spare_servers int
>
> The desired maximum number of idle server processes. Used only when pm is set to dynamic. Also mandatory in this case.
> pm.max_requests int
>
> The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning. This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS. Default value: 0.

Comment: Hey I checked the

pm.max_children = 50,
pm.start_servers = 5,
pm.min_spare_servers = 10,
pm.max_spare_servers = 35

for both systems, so I just doubled it for the larger system, it worked. Hey how do I find out the best configurations for this?
Thank you so much though.

Comment: You have to see the FPM status page to get the max listen queue,
idle processes, active processes, total processes, max active processes, max children reached, information to determine the "best" configurations. Set up tools such as Cacti http://www.cacti.net to automate it.